# JAVA + PostgreSQL + Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I want to use Spring to connect to my local PostgreSQL db. I don't know if it is possible, cause I didn't find any tutorials for this. So is it possible? If yes, please explain me where can I find some fine tutorial. If no, how can I do it? I know I can make it via postgresql jdbc, but I want to do it like in real company.

Comment: Which kind of Spring app do you intend to build? By the way, sure it is possible. You could get a look at: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html or http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/ and see which data access you like more.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.  The database vendor is immaterial.  Java hides database details using JDBC.

Here is a Spring [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) that shows you how to do it in 15 minutes or less.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a spring project from https://start.spring.io/ and add postgresql to its dependencies. You will then see it build up in your **pom.xml** file. Then you have to enter the information of the postgresql database you want to connect to in the **application.yml** file.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my example.

applicationContext.xml :

```
<!-- the setting msg  -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config/database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!--    PostgreSQL datasource -->
         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        </bean>
<!--    ibatis client -->
    <bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```